# Help verifying a contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, verify

I'm having a tough time to verify a contract. This is the contract ABI of the contract that I've deployed:

```
[
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "version",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "implementation",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Upgraded",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "newOwner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transferProxyOwnership",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "payable": true,
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "fallback"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "previousOwner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "newOwner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ProxyOwnershipTransferred",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "version",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "implementation",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "upgradeTo",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "version",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "implementation",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "data",
                "type": "bytes"
            }
        ],
        "name": "upgradeToAndCall",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": true,
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "implementation",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "proxyOwner",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "upgradeabilityOwner",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "version",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

I've tried in several ways, comparing codes, parsing the ABI at https://abi.hashex.org/ but nothing seems to work. I'm using 0.4.20 compiler with optimization enabled. This is the address of the contract in Ropsten: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x31e81f35632a5f233fd936f0c4a68698467c6326#code, and this is the code:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.20;

/**
 * @title EternalStorage
 * @dev This contract holds all the necessary state variables to carry out the storage of any contract.
 */
contract EternalStorage {

    mapping(bytes32 => uint256) internal uintStorage;
    mapping(bytes32 => string) internal stringStorage;
    mapping(bytes32 => address) internal addressStorage;
    mapping(bytes32 => bytes) internal bytesStorage;
    mapping(bytes32 => bool) internal boolStorage;
    mapping(bytes32 => int256) internal intStorage;

}



/**
 * @title UpgradeabilityOwnerStorage
 * @dev This contract keeps track of the upgradeability owner
 */
contract UpgradeabilityOwnerStorage {
  // Owner of the contract
    address private _upgradeabilityOwner;

    /**
    * @dev Tells the address of the owner
    * @return the address of the owner
    */
    function upgradeabilityOwner() public view returns (address) {
        return _upgradeabilityOwner;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Sets the address of the owner
    */
    function setUpgradeabilityOwner(address newUpgradeabilityOwner) internal {
        _upgradeabilityOwner = newUpgradeabilityOwner;
    }

}



/**
 * @title Proxy
 * @dev Gives the possibility to delegate any call to a foreign implementation.
 */
contract Proxy {

    /**
    * @dev Fallback function allowing to perform a delegatecall to the given implementation.
    * This function will return whatever the implementation call returns
    */
    function () public payable {
        address _impl = implementation();
        require(_impl != address(0));
        bytes memory data = msg.data;

        assembly {
            let result := delegatecall(gas, _impl, add(data, 0x20), mload(data), 0, 0)
            let size := returndatasize

            let ptr := mload(0x40)
            returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)

            switch result
            case 0 { revert(ptr, size) }
            default { return(ptr, size) }
        }
    }

    /**
    * @dev Tells the address of the implementation where every call will be delegated.
    * @return address of the implementation to which it will be delegated
    */
    function implementation() public view returns (address);
}



/**
 * @title UpgradeabilityStorage
 * @dev This contract holds all the necessary state variables to support the upgrade functionality
 */
contract UpgradeabilityStorage {
  // Version name of the current implementation
    string internal _version;

    // Address of the current implementation
    address internal _implementation;

    /**
    * @dev Tells the version name of the current implementation
    * @return string representing the name of the current version
    */
    function version() public view returns (string) {
        return _version;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Tells the address of the current implementation
    * @return address of the current implementation
    */
    function implementation() public view returns (address) {
        return _implementation;
    }
}



/**
 * @title UpgradeabilityProxy
 * @dev This contract represents a proxy where the implementation address to which it will delegate can be upgraded
 */
contract UpgradeabilityProxy is Proxy, UpgradeabilityStorage {
  /**
  * @dev This event will be emitted every time the implementation gets upgraded
  * @param version representing the version name of the upgraded implementation
  * @param implementation representing the address of the upgraded implementation
  */
    event Upgraded(string version, address indexed implementation);

    /**
    * @dev Upgrades the implementation address
    * @param version representing the version name of the new implementation to be set
    * @param implementation representing the address of the new implementation to be set
    */
    function _upgradeTo(string version, address implementation) internal {
        require(_implementation != implementation);
        _version = version;
        _implementation = implementation;
        Upgraded(version, implementation);
    }
}


/**
 * @title OwnedUpgradeabilityProxy
 * @dev This contract combines an upgradeability proxy with basic authorization control functionalities
 */
contract OwnedUpgradeabilityProxy is UpgradeabilityOwnerStorage, UpgradeabilityProxy {
    /**
    * @dev Event to show ownership has been transferred
    * @param previousOwner representing the address of the previous owner
    * @param newOwner representing the address of the new owner
    */
    event ProxyOwnershipTransferred(address previousOwner, address newOwner);

    /**
    * @dev the constructor sets the original owner of the contract to the sender account.
    */
    function OwnedUpgradeabilityProxy(address _owner) public {
        setUpgradeabilityOwner(_owner);
    }

    /**
    * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
    */
    modifier onlyProxyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == proxyOwner());
        _;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Tells the address of the proxy owner
    * @return the address of the proxy owner
    */
    function proxyOwner() public view returns (address) {
        return upgradeabilityOwner();
    }

    /**
    * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
    * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
    */
    function transferProxyOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyProxyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0));
        ProxyOwnershipTransferred(proxyOwner(), newOwner);
        setUpgradeabilityOwner(newOwner);
    }

    /**
    * @dev Allows the upgradeability owner to upgrade the current version of the proxy.
    * @param version representing the version name of the new implementation to be set.
    * @param implementation representing the address of the new implementation to be set.
    */
    function upgradeTo(string version, address implementation) public onlyProxyOwner {
        _upgradeTo(version, implementation);
    }

    /**
    * @dev Allows the upgradeability owner to upgrade the current version of the proxy and call the new implementation
    * to initialize whatever is needed through a low level call.
    * @param version representing the version name of the new implementation to be set.
    * @param implementation representing the address of the new implementation to be set.
    * @param data represents the msg.data to bet sent in the low level call. This parameter may include the function
    * signature of the implementation to be called with the needed payload
    */
    function upgradeToAndCall(string version, address implementation, bytes data) payable public onlyProxyOwner {
        upgradeTo(version, implementation);
        require(this.call.value(msg.value)(data));
    }
}


/**
 * @title EternalStorageProxy
 * @dev This proxy holds the storage of the token contract and delegates every call to the current implementation set.
 * Besides, it allows to upgrade the token's behaviour towards further implementations, and provides basic
 * authorization control functionalities
 */
contract EternalStorageProxyForStormMultisender is OwnedUpgradeabilityProxy, EternalStorage {

    function EternalStorageProxyForStormMultisender(address _owner) public OwnedUpgradeabilityProxy(_owner) {}

}
```

Any idea of what's going on?
Thanks.

Comment: URL in Ropsten https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x31e81f35632a5f233fd936f0c4a68698467c6326#code

Comment: What's the name of the contract? Run solc -version and get the compiler version

Comment: Compiler version is 0.4.20+commit.3155dd80.Emscripten.clang.

Comment: The name of the contract is EternalStorageProxyForStormMultisender. I´m using Remix to deploy it.

Comment: Is the _owner created by the constructor "function EternalStorageProxyForStormMultisender(address _owner)" address "0xC349954E5e620aCBB060b52B24a90A59d3eb10e8"?

Comment: Just to make it sure, I´ve deployed the contract again 2 times. First without optimization, the url is https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x03969b81d725538fa9dd6b8652e632688617ee2ac227fd25225d7121a45f7bd9

Comment: The second deploy has optimization enabled, and the url is https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x28b8494d5918c423b08dda67e2d9c63a1f4950e079e448a782508a71fef57ba8

Comment: And the address of the address _owner it should be address of the account where I deployed the contract, which in this case for the new contracts that I just have deployed is 0x6Ae43AA424cDc2a2431b951C7e661DF60dBAa3Da

Comment: @dangerousfood, yes 0xC349954E5e620aCBB060b52B24a90A59d3eb10e8 is the address of the first contract that I deployed at https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x31e81f35632a5f233fd936f0c4a68698467c6326#code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your configuration.

I have taken the code above and compiled it with remix using `0.4.20+commit.3155dd80.Emscripten.clang` and `optimization:yes`. I deployed EternalStorageProxyForStormMultisender with the _owner in the constructor method being `0xC349954E5e620aCBB060b52B24a90A59d3eb10e8`.

Deployment of that contract can be found [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x113bf0c57cb30dfe7dc5c8fd6789f8c59ca89e90#code)

Doing a comparison of the deployed byte code:[image]
**Left** original contract [0x31e81f35632a5f233fd936f0c4a68698467c6326](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x31e81f35632a5f233fd936f0c4a68698467c6326#code)

**Right** is the contract I deployed [0x113bf0c57cb30dfe7dc5c8fd6789f8c59ca89e90](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x113bf0c57cb30dfe7dc5c8fd6789f8c59ca89e90#code)

Don't be discouraged though. The Etherscan tool for "Publish and Verify" is objectively terrible.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to use the address in the constructor argument. I already deployed the contract correctly, many thanks.

Comment: I´m new here, how can I thank your help? There is any kind of voting?

Comment: That's great. Yes, if you upvote my answer above and hit the green check mark to accept the answer. Both of those things would be good for me